# Using an eigenfunction expansion to solve $y''(x) + y(x) = \cos x$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

Hello people im new to this site and have a problem i cant seem to solve:

Use the method of eigenfunction expansions to solve

$y''(x) + y(x) = \cos x$ $∀x ∈ (0, π)$ subject to $\left\{
\begin{array}{c l} 
    y(0)=0  \\
     y(\pi)=0
\end{array}\right.$

Ive been stuck on this for quite a while so any help will be appreciated

Comment: Welcome! It is always helpful to let us know what you have tried so far, and where exactly you are getting stuck. Nice LaTeX, by the way!

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Do you know how to find the eigenfunctions in question?

Comment: Im firstly stuck with what the eigenvalue would be in this question. Im not incredibly sure. @TheCount

Comment: The initial conditions are written correctly @Moo